# I need to show some text in DIV tag with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Could you help me, i have not knowledge of Angular. I need to show some text in DIV tag. Visibility condition is returning from JS function: isShowing. Text contains HTML tags and is returning from JS function: agreementMessage.

```
<div ng-controller="formController" class="container" id="container">
    <div class="agreement-signed-message" ng-if="isShowing()">{{showAgreementMessage()}}</div>
</div>


function showAgreementMessage() {
    return "message";
}

function isShowing() {
    return true;
}
```

This is demo functions.

Comment: You are meant to use () after the function name

Comment: AngularJS v1.6.2

Comment: This is not React. You can not interpolate HTML-Element tags here. Only plain strings, numbers 'n stuff. I reckon this is the main problem you're facing here. What does your browser's console say? Any error output?

Comment: No effect absolutely, no errors in browser console

Comment: Do you get any output if `agreementMessage()` returns a plain string like **test** or so? Please post additionally the code of `isShowing()`

Comment: I want to void JS function. This function must return message and conditions of visibility

Comment: Can you please add both methods to your post? `agreementMessage()` and `isShowing()`?

Comment: I have added my two demo functions.

Comment: Your function is called showAgreementMessage(), but you're calling just agreementMessage()

Comment: Sorry, i have mistake with function name, now it`s correct.  I have added parent tag. I think about controller - formController. May be i can use formController to insert my message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually don't see a problem with the code you are using if you move both the `function`s to the `formController`.

Forgetting to add them to `$scope` will cause your `formController` to not be able see them.

```js
var app = angular.module("Test", []);

var formController = function($scope) {

  $scope.showAgreementMessage = function() {
    return "messagesdf";
  }

  $scope.isShowing = function() {
    return true;
  }
}

app.controller(formController, ["$scope", "formController"]);

// Don't do this. Add them to formController
// function showAgreementMessage() { ... }
// function isShowing() { ... }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="Test">
  <div ng-controller="formController" class="container" id="container">
    <div class="agreement-signed-message" ng-if="isShowing()">
      {{ showAgreementMessage() }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$scope` to invoke the function from your HTML (View) to your controller by **binding**:

```js
function DemoCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.showAgreementMessage = function() {
      return "message";
  }

  $scope.isShowing = function() {
      return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl" ng-app> 
  <div class="agreement-signed-message" ng-if="isShowing()">{{showAgreementMessage()}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, but it`s late. @Jimenemex has answered first ))

Comment: This answer won't work with AngularJS  V1.6. See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Migrating to V1.3 - controllers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#controllers).